# Applying Fourier transform to solve a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R^n})$ be a weak solution of $-\Delta u+u=f$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I am trying to solve one problem and the first step should be to apply the Fourier transform to both members of the equation and I am a bit confused.

I know that I can apply Fourier transform to both members because $u, f$ are in $L^2$ and so are tempered distributions, and $\Delta u$ makes sense as a tempered distribution. Also, since $u$ is a weak solution I know that $$\int\nabla u\nabla v+\int uv =\int fv \enspace\enspace\enspace\forall v\in H^1_0.$$

Now my question is on how to apply Fourier transform to both members: do I write, for example, the FT of $f$ seeing $f$ as a distribution or a function of $L^2$? And is this what we get as the FT of $\Delta$:

$$\langle F(-\Delta u),\varphi \rangle  = \langle-\Delta u, Fv \rangle = \sum_i \langle u_{x_i}, (Fv)_{x_i} \rangle = \sum_i \langle  u_{x_i}, F(-2\pi i xv) \rangle =\int \nabla u F(-2\pi ixv)?$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: How about applying the FT without multiplying by a test function $v$?  Just
$$
F( - \triangle u) + F(u) = F(f) ?
$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is this what I should get? $$(4\pi^2 |\nabla u|^2)F(u)+F(u)=F(f)$$?

Comment: No, there should not be any derivatives of $u$ appearing.  See row 106 in this table: {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships}

Comment: Sorry, of course, my bad; I meant $4\pi^2 |x|^2F(u)+F(u)=F(f)$. Can I do anything from here?

Comment: Only instead of $x$ (the original space variable) I would use $\xi$ (the dual space variable), since the FT takes us into the dual space.  Anyway, from here we solve for $F(u)$:
$$
F(u) = {F(f) \over 1 + 4 \pi^2 |\xi|^2},
$$
and by taking the inverse Fourier transform on both sides, we get--at least in principle--the desired solution $u$.